# Me Filter Issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have added the following field to a custom list definition based on custom content type.

```
<Field Type="User" DisplayName="Line Manager" List="UserInfo" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" ShowField="ImnName" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" UserSelectionScope="0" ID="{098E0A5A-8187-481E-B155-B674A406EEAF}" SourceID="{53ca79b7-9ffa-457d-aff8-c71508b09cb1}" StaticName="Line_x0020_Manager" Name="Line_x0020_Manager" RowOrdinal="32" Filterable="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE"/>
```

I am putting [Me] filter on this column in a view. The filter is not able to filter the records for the logged in user.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Interestingly if I add similar column through SharePoint UI the filter works fine. Any clues, ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew!! This got resolved and was one of the most frustrating things. I am not sure if this was an issue with the way I defined the schema below or whether it’s a bug with SharePoint.

I ran a profiler to see what’s going on under the hoods and found a query (pretty huge for me to digest ) where in the RowOrdinal was being used extensively with a predefined value as 0 or 1. As I was using “32” as RowOrdinal, it looked shady to me. I changed it to “0” and bingo!! The filter started working.

BTW here is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx) says about it – "Optional Integer. Specifies the database location for the field."

Doesn’t appear like it should take part in records filtering.

So, to close the field should be defined as

```
<Field Type="User" DisplayName="Line Manager" List="UserInfo" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" ShowField="ImnName" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" UserSelectionScope="0" ID="{098E0A5A-8187-481E-B155-B674A406EEAF}" SourceID="{53ca79b7-9ffa-457d-aff8-c71508b09cb1}" StaticName="Line_x0020_Manager" Name="Line_x0020_Manager" RowOrdinal="0" Filterable="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the [Me] filter work on native list definition?
Or, are you sure that your SharePoint installation using English version?

Maybe you should change field type from "User" to "people or group"

Comment: Yes it is and hence I am all confused. It's english version so filter has to be [Me]. I guess in the schema for person and group the field type is user only.